# Decimal Time of Day Conversion

Tags: code-golf, string, date, floating-point

## Introduction

Time is confusing. Sixty seconds to a minute, sixty minutes to an hour, twenty-four hours to a day (and not to mention that pesky am/pm!).

There's no room for such silliness nowadays, so we've decided to adopt the only sensible alternative: decimal days! That is to say, each day is considered 1 whole unit, and anything shorter is written as a decimal fraction of that day. So, for example: "12:00:00" would be written as "0.5", and "01:23:45" might be written as "0.058159".

Because it will take time to get used to the new system, you are tasked with writing a program that can convert between them in both directions.

## Challenge

Write a program in the language of your choice, that given a modern time in the ISO-8601 format of "hh:mm:ss", will return the equivalent decimal fraction unit. Likewise, given a decimal fraction, the program should return the time in the modern format initially specified.

You can make the following assumptions:

- The modern time input and output can range from "00:00:00" to "24:00:00"
- The decimal time input and output can range from "0" to "1", and should be able to accept/output up to at least 5 decimal places (such as "0.12345"). More precision is acceptable
- The program should be able to know which conversion direction to perform based on input
- You cannot use time related functions/libraries

The winner will be determined by the shortest code that accomplishes the criteria. They will be selected in at least 7 decimal day units, or if/when there have been enough submissions.

## Examples

Here's a(n intentionally) poorly written piece of JavaScript code to be used as an example:

```
function decimalDay(hms) {
    var x, h, m, s;
    if (typeof hms === 'string' && hms.indexOf(':') > -1) {
        x = hms.split(':');
        return (x[0] * 3600 + x[1] * 60 + x[2] * 1) / 86400;
    }
    h = Math.floor(hms * 24) % 24;
    m = Math.floor(hms * 1440) % 60;
    s = Math.floor(hms * 86400) % 60;
    return (h > 9 ? '' : '0') + h + ':' + (m > 9 ? '' : '0') + m + ':' + (s > 9 ? '' : '0') + s;
}
decimalDay('02:57:46'); // 0.12344907407407407
decimalDay('23:42:12'); // 0.9876388888888888
decimalDay(0.5); // 12:00:00
decimalDay(0.05816); // 01:23:45
```

Comment: Hmm... 60 is *almost* 64. I wonder what time would be like if there were 64 seconds in a minute and 64 minutes in an hour (and 16 or 32 hours in a day).

Comment: Do we have to handle leap seconds? so 23:59:60 is 1 second from the end of a 86401 second day?

Comment: @Sparr No need to worry about leap seconds. This is the future, where we have decided that it's silly for a second to be considered an absolute value while also tying it to the relative speed of the rotation of the earth ;)

Comment: @MichaelT It'd be a programmers dream world =P

Comment: @Mwr247 yep. DNS TTL has (had?) a field that is `n` where `n` is 2^n seconds.  So a value of '6' had a TTL of about 1 minute. A value of '12' had a TTL of about 1 hour. '15' was about 8 hours and so on. It allowed one byte to define the timeout and give you enough control for short or long times.

Comment: For those looking for loopholes, note that MicroSoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc already use floating point as their internal representations of dates and times! They both have scripting languages built-in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CJam, <s>58 56</s> 42 bytes

I am sure this is too long and can be golfed a lot. But here goes for starters:

```
86400q':/:d_,({60bd\/}{~*i60b{s2Ue[}%':*}?
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=86400q'%3A%2F%3Ad_%2C(%7B60bd%5C%2F%7D%7B~*i60b%7Bs2Ue%5B%7D%25'%3A*%7D%3F&input=0.9998842592592593)

Comment: Heh, we have similar ideas

Comment: @aditsu Oh!. Didn't see yours before updating mine and then was in a hurry to commute.

Comment: You know what.. feel free to use my code: `86400q':/:d_,({60bd\/}{~*mo60bAfmd2/':*}?`, I'm deleting my answer. The `mo` is so that 0.058159 converts to 01:23:45

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>159</s> <s>150</s> 141 + 2 = 143 Bytes

Straightforward solution, can probably be much shorter. Will work on it.

*Added two bytes to account for input needing to be enclosed in "s. Also, Sp3000 pointed out an issue with eval() interpreting octals, and showed a way to shorten formatting, use map() and remove one print.*

```py
n=input();i=float;d=864e2
if':'in n:a,b,c=map(i,n.split(':'));o=a/24+b/1440+c/d
else:n=i(n);o=(':%02d'*3%(n*24,n*1440%60,n*d%60))[1:]
print o
```

[Check it out on ideone here.](http://ideone.com/WVPBAO)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (*ES6*), <strike>116</strike> 110 bytes

```js
f=x=>x[0]?([h,m,s]=x.split(':'),+s+m*60+h*3600)/86400:[24,60,60].map(y=>('0'+~~(x*=y)%60).slice(-2)).join(':')


// for snippet demo:
i=prompt();
i=i==+i?+i:i; // convert decimal string to number type
alert(f(i))
```

**Commented:**

```js
f=x=>
    x[0] ? // if x is a string (has a defined property at '0')
        ([h, m, s] = x.split(':'), // split into hours, minutes, seconds
        +s + m*60 + h*3600) // calculate number of seconds
        / 86400 // divide by seconds in a day
    : // else
        [24, 60, 60]. // array of hours, minutes, seconds
        map(y=> // map each with function
            ('0' + // prepend with string zero
                ~~(x *= y) // multiply x by y and floor it
                % 60 // get remainder
            ).slice(-2) // get last 2 digits
        ).join(':') // join resulting array with colons
```

Comment: `24:00:00` produces `1` but the inverse is not true

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 fixed

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>152</s> <s>143</s> 142 bytes

Well, I updated my approach to be less "Julian," as they say, for the sake of golfing. For a better (though less concise) approach, see the revision history.

```matlab
x->(t=[3600,60,1];d=86400;typeof(x)<:String?dot(int(split(x,":")),t)/d:(x*=d;o="";for i=t q,x=x÷i,x%i;o*=lpad(int(q),2,0)*":"end;o[1:end-1]))
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts a string or a 64-bit floating point number and returns a 64-bit floating point number or string, respectively. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=x->...`.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```matlab
function f(x)
    # Construct a vector of the number of seconds in an hour,
    # minute, and second
    t = [3600, 60, 1]

    # Store the number of seconds in 24 hours
    d = 86400

    # Does the type of x inherit from the type String?
    if typeof(x) <: String
        # Compute the total number of observed seconds as the
        # dot product of the time split into a vector with the
        # number of seconds in an hour, minute, and second
        s = dot(int(split(x, ":")), t)

        # Get the proportion of the day by dividing this by
        # the number of seconds in 24 hours
        s / d
    else
        # Convert x to the number of observed seconds
        x *= d

        # Initialize an output string
        o = ""

        # Loop over the number of seconds in each time unit
        for i in t
            # Set q to be the quotient and x to be the remainder
            # from x divided by i
            q, x = divrem(x, i)

            # Append q to o, padded with zeroes as necessary
            o *= lpad(int(q), 2, 0) * ":"
        end

        # o has a trailing :, so return everything up to that
        o[1:end-1]
    end
end
```

Examples:

```matlab
julia> f("23:42:12")
0.9876388888888888

julia> f(0.9876388888888888)
"23:42:12"

julia> f(f("23:42:12"))
"23:42:12"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3: 143 Bytes

```
i,k,l,m=input(),60,86400,float
if'.'in i:i=m(i)*l;m=(3*':%02d'%(i/k/k,i/k%k,i%k))[1:]
else:a,b,c=map(m,i.split(':'));m=(a*k*k+b*k+c)/l
print(m)
```

Same byte count as the python 2 solution but it seems we took different approaches to the maths.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 137 bytes

Full C program. Takes input on stdin and outputs on stdout.

```c
main(c){float a,b;scanf("%f:%f:%d",&a,&b,&c)<3?c=a*86400,printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",c/3600,c/60%60,c%60):printf("%f",a/24+b/1440+c/86400.);}
```

Ungolfed and commented:

```c
int main() {
    // b is float to save a . on 1440
    float a,b;
    // c is int to implicitly cast floats
    int c;

    // If the input is hh:mm:ss it gets splitted into a, b, c
    // Three arguments are filled, so ret = 3
    // If the input is a float, it gets stored in a
    // scanf stops at the first semicolon and only fills a, so ret = 1
    int ret = scanf("%f:%f:%d", &a, &b, &c);

    if(ret < 3) {
        // Got a float, convert to time
        // c = number of seconds from 00:00:00
        c = a * 86400;
        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", c/3600, c/60 % 60, c%60);
    }
    else {
        // a = hh, b = mm, c = ss
        // In one day there are:
        // 24 hours
        // 1440 minutes
        // 86400 seconds
        printf("%f", a/24 + b/1440 + c/86400.);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clear use of scanf and %f

Comment: D'oh! I meant "clever".

Comment: Your `c` is `int` therefore `c/86400=0`

Answer (score 2):

## J, 85 bytes

Results:

T '12:00:00'
0.5

T 0.5
12 0 0

T '12:34:56'
0.524259

T 0.524259
12 34 56

```
T=:3 :'a=.86400 if.1=#y do.>.(24 60 60#:y*a)else.a%~+/3600 60 1*".y#~#:192 24 3 end.'
```

Total 85

Comment: Welcome to the site! I edited your post so that the code will be displayed as code. As for an online link, the best one I know of is [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/j). I would give you a link, but I'm not experienced with J, so I don't know the right way to invoke it. Also, this seems to be 91 bytes when you include the first and last lines. Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for your help! The program [a=... to end.] Is 77. The title is 10. The terminator is 1, so that makes 88. With three line feeds that makes 91! I'll work on it :o)

Comment: Now down to an 85 byte one-liner!

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>194</s> <s>192</s> <s>190</s> 188 bytes

```
function(z){if(isNaN(z)){x=z.split(':');return x[0]/24+x[1]/1440+x[2]/86400}h=(z*24)|0;h%=24;m=(z*1440)|0;m%=60;s=(z*86400)|0;s%=60;return""+(h>9?'':0)+h+':'+(m>9?'':0)+m+':'+(s>9?'':0)+s}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>98</s> 130 bytes

```
s=>s==+s?'246060'.replace(/../g,l=>':'+('0'+~~(s*=+l)%60).slice(-2)).slice(1):s.split`:`.reduce((a,b)=>+b+(+a)*60)*1/864e2;f(0.5);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, time related functions (such as "Date" and "toTimeString") are not allowed in this challenge. Otherwise, it's a much more concise way of doing it =)

Comment: @Mwr247 oh did not see that, I'll be fixing this then

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>156</s> 152 bytes

I thought it is going to be easy for C. But still ended up quite large. :(

```c
n,m=60;d(char*s){strchr(s,58)?printf("%f",(float)(atoi(s)*m*m+atoi(s+3)*m+atoi(s+6))/m/m/24):printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",(n=atof(s)*m*m*24)/m/m,n/m%m,n%m);}
```

Test Program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n,m=60;
d(char*s)
{
    strchr(s,':') ? 
        printf("%f",(float)(atoi(s)*m*m+atoi(s+3)*m+atoi(s+6))/m/m/24):
        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d",(n=atof(s)*m*m*24)/m/m,n/m%m,n%m);
}

int main()
{
    d("01:23:45");
    printf("\n");
    d("02:57:46");
    printf("\n");
    d("23:42:12");
    printf("\n");
    d("12:00:00");
    printf("\n");
    d("0.5");
    printf("\n");
    d("0.05816");
    printf("\n");
    d("0");
    printf("\n");
    d("1");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```c
0.058160
0.123449
0.987639
0.500000
12:00:00
01:23:45
00:00:00
24:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```php
<?=strpos($t=$argv[1],58)?strtotime($t)/86400:date("H:i:s",$t*86400);
```

takes input from command line argument, prints to STDOUT:

If input contains a colon, convert to unix time and divide by (seconds per day),
else multply numeric value with (seconds per day) and format unix time to `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: No time function

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>109</s> <s>108</s> 101 + 6 (`-plaF:` flag) = 107 bytes

```
$_=$#F?($F[0]*60+$F[1]+$F[2]/60)/1440:sprintf"%02d:%02d:%02d",$h=$_*24,$m=($h-int$h)*60,($m-int$m)*60
```

Using:

```
perl -plaF: -e '$_=$#F?($F[0]*60+$F[1]+$F[2]/60)/1440:sprintf"%02d:%02d:%02d",$h=$_*24,$m=($h-int$h)*60,($m-int$m)*60' <<< 01:23:45
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/6pWG2B)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 178 bytes

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,2)="0.",TEXT(FLOOR(A1*24,1),"00")&":"&TEXT(MOD(FLOOR(A1*1440,1),60),"00")&":"&TEXT(MOD(FLOOR(A1*86400,1),60),"00"),((LEFT(A1,2)*60+MID(A1,4,2))*60+RIGHT(A1,2))/86400)
```